# F# set property in constructor of derived type

Tags: f#

I have a type that inherits from the MVC class [AuthorizeAttribute](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs). In my constructor (which takes a parameter), I want to set the Roles property but I am getting an error "This is not a valid object construction expression. Explicit object constructors must either call an alternate constructor or initialize all fields of the object and specify a call to a super class constructor." Can someone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

Attempt #1:

```
type MyAuthorizer =
    inherit AuthorizeAttribute

    new([<ParamArray>] roles : string[]) =
        let x = new MyAuthorizer()
        //x.Roles <- ""
        x
```

Attempt #2. (same error):

```
type MyAuthorizer =
    inherit AuthorizeAttribute

    new([<ParamArray>] roles : string[]) =
        {
            inherit AuthorizeAttribute
            Roles = ""
        }
```

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5307252/126014

Comment: @MarkSeemann Not the same case. Here it has to call the base constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try including the property and its value in the call to the base constructor, like this:

```
type MyAuthorizer([<ParamArray>] roles : string[])    
    inherit AuthorizeAttribute(Roles = "")
```

Comment: very elegant. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is a bit confusing, but this should work. Notice the `then` keyword, which allows you to do arbitrary side effects, such as assigning the value of `Roles`.

```
type MyAuthorizer =
    inherit AuthorizeAttribute

    new ([<ParamArray>] roles : string[]) as this = 
        { inherit AuthorizeAttribute() } then
            this.Roles <- ""
```

Comment: This also seems to work! Thank you. Can you explain or point me in the right direction what "then" does?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/constructors-%5Bfsharp%5D#executing-side-effects-in-constructors has an explanation.

Comment: Link is broken, [updated link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/constructors#executing-side-effects-in-constructors)